# Show upload progress indicator on top using getx

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I am working on video uploading using the [flutter_uploader](https://stackoverflow.com) package. So a progress needs to be shown on the top, during video uploading. How to achieve this in flutter using getx package? Or any other alternative methods are available?

Answer (score 0):

Call api fun and as well as show uploading percentage on a custom dialog,
Like this-

```
 () async {

        _storiesController.createStory(widget.path);
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return WillPopScope(
              onWillPop: () async => false,
              child: AlertDialog(
                title: Row(
                    children:[
                     CircularProgressIndicator(),
                     Obx(()=> Text('   Uploading ${(_storiesController.progressBar.value*100).toInt()}%'))
                    ]
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("SKIP"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.back();
                      Get.back();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
```

**get percentage from api **

```
onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
      final progress = sent / total;
      print('progress: $progress ($sent/$total)');
      // setState(() {
      progressBar.value = sent / total;
      test.value = progressBar.value.toString();
      print('actual uploading :${progressBar.value}');
      // });
    },
```